# How to make a Java 32bit web app run on fully 64 bit machine?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, web, 64-bit

I have a a web application run by a stand alone tomcat server  on a 32bit machine, now I decided to move it to a fully 64bit environment machine,  everything will be 64bit tomcat, java .. etc.

I did the transferring and deployment of the needed files.  Then started the server but I can view my app it's throwing error: "Servlet someservlet threw load() exception"

Is there a required step on transferring a 32bit origin web application to a fully 64bit machine?

Here is the stack trace:

```
Nov 15, 2013 4:28:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet MeritOrderLoader as unavailable
Nov 15, 2013 4:28:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet threw load() exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:974)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool.borrowObject(AbandonedObjectPool.java:84)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
    at trader.main.com.quantrisk.util.DatabaseConnectionFactory.getConnection(DatabaseConnectionFactory.java:38)
```

Comment: You should probably read the exception stack trace carefully. You know, it might actually tell you what's wrong.

Comment: There is no such thing as 64-bit Tomcat. Java is platform independent, as long as you do not use some funky JNI libraries which are indeed platform dependent

Comment: @Kal The OP may be using a double-click *cough*Windows*cough* installer that includes Tomcat and a JVM in one package.

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace?

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan stack trace added in the post. You can have a look at it.  I don't really know why it happened.  I'm confused right now.

Comment: @Kal What do you mean by "funky JNI" ?

Comment: You have code which recurses too deeply to throw Stackoverflow error. Check your Datasource / driver configurations

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan that's the strange thing cause will I tried to run it just using eclipse it runs fine, eclipse is in 32 bit, then When I deployed it on a tomcat on a 64bit machine I get this errors.

Comment: @AndrexLoyloy And this is the same exact identical `war` file you're using on both? You're sure you're not using the exploded layout when launching from Eclipse? Have you tried the `war` in a 32-bit JVM?

Comment: @chrylis In eclipse I used only the classes it built and started it.  But for the tomcat on the 64bit machine I used the exported war that was produced by eclipse when you go to Right Click->export->war file.

I will try to use the files that are built by eclipse and not a war file.

Comment: @AndrexLoyloy Use that `war` file in Tomcat running on a 32-bit JVM. You'll probably get the same exception.

Comment: Check your deployment assembly of your project properties whether all the required jars are present?

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan I don't know what exactly you meant by "Check your deployment assembly whether all the required jars are present"
But when the war file was extracted and I checked the web-inf/lib folder, all of the jars are there.

Comment: @AndrexLoyloy I mean using any JNI library in general.

Comment: I tried running the application on eclipse and not a stand alone tomcat but still it has the same error.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're using a native 32-bit library, then no, you don't need any change to your Java program; that's the intent behind the platform-independent bytecode approach. Most likely, there's some difference in the Tomcat installations, perhaps in the classpath.

Comment: How can I tell if I used a native 32-bit library?  I included quite a few jar files.

Comment: @AndrexLoyloy If necessary, look in the jar and see if it has `.so` or `.dll` files. The MySQL JDBC driver doesn't; this is almost certainly a config problem.

Comment: where excatly can I see those .so or .dll files?

Comment: @AndrexLoyloy ...in the jar file?

Comment: so you are saying that I should check the jar file I have?  There are so many can you show some quick possible way of doing it?

Comment: @AndrexLoyloy Did you try my suggestion of running the war in a 32-bit installation?

Comment: issue is resolved now thanks,  no problem with the jars it was some hidden configuration of the application. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.  Application went into an infinite loop, because of some hidden configuration of the application.  Thanks for the help.